# ubuntu upgrade apt conflicts

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04, ubiquity

I have a ubiquity xg-server which i just upgraded from ubuntu 16 to 18

i noticed a lot of stuff got disabled mainly due to being 3rd party repos. 
I reenabled the ones i had and started to enable all my software.

I am getting this error however:

```
ubnt@ubnt:/tmp$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Conflicts: mongodb-server but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 mongodb-org-shell : Conflicts: mongodb-server but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 mongodb-server : Depends: mongodb-clients but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ubnt@ubnt:/tmp$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not installed
 unifi-video : Depends: mongodb-10gen (>= 2.4.10) but it is not installable or
                        mongodb-org-server (>= 2.6.0) but it is not installed or
                        mongodb-server (>= 2.4.9) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ubnt@ubnt:/tmp$ sudo apt --fix-broken install                                                  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1 libboost-program-options1.65.1
  libboost-system1.65.1 libstemmer0d mongo-tools mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/63.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 226 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 111690 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.0.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.0.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.9_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I noticed of interest: `Conflicts: mongodb-server but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try remove the conflicted package `sudo apt remove mongo-tools mongodb-server-core`, then run `sudo apt -f install`.

Comment: You have multiple problems - I see package conflicts, version conflicts, and orphans. Exactly which problem do you want help with?

Comment: @user535733 All?

Comment: @Emmet When i try to remove those  it states that i should run --fix-broken install , which then fails as above.

Comment: Solving "all": Remember those disabled non-Ubuntu repositories? The repos are gone, but the installed non-Ubuntu packages are still there. Find and remove those packages. Oh, and run autoremove like the system is telling you to.